# Navigate in Angular 7 without adding parameter to URL

Tags: javascript, angular, post, routes, angular7

I want to navigate between two routes in Angular 7 with posting data between them. But I don;t want to show those parameter in URL. How to do it in proper way?

at this moment I am strugging with something like this:

`this.router.navigate(['/my-new-route', {data1: 'test', test2: 2323, test: 'AAAAAAA'}]);`

and it change my url to

`http://localhost:4200/my-new-route;data1=test;test2=2323;test=AAAAAAA`

how to do it to cancel those data from url:

`http://localhost:4200/my-new-route`

Edit:

My case:

1. /form - route with some form
2. /options - route with some data

on /form route - users have some form with empty fields to fill manually

but on /options page there is some preset configuration, when user choose one is navigated to /form and fields are fill autmatically

when they move back to another page and back again to /form - should see empty form. Only link from /options to /form should fill those fields.

Comment: besides the shared service, another option is via the state field of the NavigationExtras https://stackoverflow.com/a/58915055/2583579

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a service and share it between both the components (the one that you're moving from, and the one that you're moving to).

Declare all the parameters that you want to pass to the URL, in the service, and before the `router.navigate([])`, set the values for parameters in the service.

You can access those parameters from the other component with that service.

Example:

**SharedService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedService {
    data1;
    test2;
    test;
}
```

**Component1**

```
import { SharedService } from 'location';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
...
constructor(private _sharedService: SharedService,
            private _router: Router) { }
...
this._sharedService.data1 = 'test'
this._sharedService.test2 = 2323;
this._sharedService.test = 'AAAAAAAA';
this._router.navigate(['/my-new-route']);
...
```

**Component2**

```
import { SharedService } from 'location';
...
private test2;
private test;
private data1;
constructor(private _sharedService: SharedService){ }
ngOnInit() {
    this.data1 = this._sharedService.data1;
    this.test2 = this._sharedService.test2;
    this.test = this._sharedService.test;
    ...
}
```

Comment: it's fine solution. But I would like to set those data only navigate from one url to second. In this solution when I set sharedService data once and navigate to the secound route later from different path those value will be set already. Nothing will clear it. I can do it on begining second route - but I don't know if it ok.


generally I have case like this:

on /form route I have some form with empty fields.User should fill them.But there is option to navigate from one page and prefill this form with some data.So from /create url i want to post some data to /form and fill it partially.

Comment: @MichałFejer You can use the ngOnDestroy() method in any component to clear those values whenever you want, or as you said you can clear them after you've accessed them.

Comment: Loosing Data on Page Reload.

Comment: This doesn't work for me... The data is empty on the new route

Answer (score 9):

There are few ways to do it.

**Try 1 :**

```
this.router.navigate(['/some-url'], { queryParams:  filter, skipLocationChange: true});
```

**Try 2 :**

We can use this work around instead by using EventEmitter and BehaviorSubject with a shared service

In component 1:

```
this.router.navigate(['url']).then(()=>
    this.service.emmiter.emit(data)
)
```

In service :

```
emmiter : EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
```

In component 2: inside constructor

```
this.service.emmiter.subscribe();
```

Comment: never use `EventEmitter` inside a service. These are solely to be used in combination with `@Output()` inside a component.

Comment: what is service in second example? Do you have somewhere full example?

Answer (score 8):

another solution for passing information from one route to another without touching the query params is via the [state](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#state) field of [NavigationExtras](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras) (as of Angular 7.2+)

something along these lines

```
// Publish
<a
  [routerLink]="['/studies', study.id]"
  [state]="{ highlight: true }">
  {{study.title}}
</a>
```

```
// Subscribe
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, ...) {
}

public highlight: boolean;

public ngOnInit() {
...
    this.route.paramMap
      .pipe(map(() => window.history.state))
      .subscribe(state => {
        this.highlight = state && state.highlight;
    });
...
}
```

```
// Alternative
constructor(private router: Router, ...) {
}

public highlight: boolean;

public ngOnInit() {
...
    this.router.events.pipe(
      filter(e => e instanceof NavigationStart),
      map(() => this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state)
    )
    .subscribe(state => {
        this.highlight = state && state.highlight;
    })
...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

pass value through "state" key from which you want to naviagte to next component:

```
//From where we Navigate
import {ActivatedRoute, NavigationExtras, Router} from "@angular/router";
export class MainPageComponent {
  constructor(public router:Router) {}
   navWithExtraValue () {
          const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
            state: {
                editMode: true
            },
        };
      }
  }


 //In constructor where we Navigated
 constructor(public router:Router,
    public route:ActivatedRoute){
      this.route.queryParams.subscribe(data=> {
        if (this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state) {
            this.editMode = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.editMode;
        }
    });
```

We don't see these value in url

Comment: Thanks for this solution!
I have my tsconfig set to strict, so I had to add a bit more checks: `constructor(private readonly _router: Router,
    private readonly _route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this._route.queryParams.subscribe(data => {
      if (this._router.getCurrentNavigation()?.extras?.state ?? false) {
        const showNewAddedDraft = this._router.getCurrentNavigation()?.extras?.state?.["showNewDraftReportAdded"];
        if(showNewAddedDraft === true) {
          //do your thing
        }
      }
    });
  }`