# send data when routing angular 6

Tags: angular6

i want to show a message in my authentification page when my token expires.
the app has a guard that checks in every request if user is still authenticated or not(token is still valid or not).
my problem is when i used localstorage and session storageto store the variable "expired". expired has always true since it's stored in the navigator. Any other solutions?
I am new to angular so please any help ?

what i want to show in my login page if expired is true:

```
        <span *ngIf="expired" class="help-block text-danger">
             Votre session a expiré !
           </span>
```

and here is the guard code :

```
  @Injectable()
     export class AuthGuard implements CanActivateChild {

     constructor(private router: Router, private localSt: 
         LocalStorageService, private loginService: LoginService) {
     }

    canActivateChild(childRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: 
     RouterStateSnapshot) {
            if (this.loginService.isAuthenticated()) {
               sessionStorage.setItem("expired", 'false');
              return true;
        }
       sessionStorage.setItem("expired", 'true');
       this.router.navigate(['/login']);
       return false;
   }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53517410/navigate-in-angular-7-without-adding-parameter-to-url/53517738#53517738

Answer (score 0):

what I do to show "The session has expired" is:

If the user is idle, or navigating to a URL without the proper permissions I send him/her to the login page through a function on a shared service

```
endSesion( message ) {

  window.localStorage.clear(); //to clear all session variables, tokens and stuff
  window.localStorage.setItem('message',message) // save as the only left thing in LS
  this.router.navigate(['login']);

}
```

And in the `constructor` or the `ngOnInit` of the login component

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.message = window.localStorage.getItem('message'); // get the message from LS
    if ( this.message ) {
        alert('Dude!: ' + this.message ); //maybe sweetalert will be nicer to look at
    }
}
```

This way you dont only use to throw user out beacuse a session expired but maybe if not permission or maybe if you check another security issue even froma backend response.